# Checkbox list for content type in drupal 7

Tags: entities, nodes

How do you add Content type checkbox list in Drupal 7?

I have content type "Exporter". When I edit an exporter I would like to have a list of regions that exporter is part of. In Drupal 7 how do I add a radio button field that list all regions in the exporter content type.

In Drupal 6 I had to use CCK, but I thought this was supported natively in Drupal 7?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right...the CCK module has now been incorporated natively into Drupal 7, so you would use that.

Just visit http://mysite.com/admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/fields to add the fields to your content type in pretty much exactly the same way you did using CCK in Drupal 6.

**EDIT**

Sorry I understand your problem now, the node reference and user reference modules aren't part of the default field system in Drupal 7; you just need to download and install the [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references) and then you'll have the "Node Reference" option in your field type drop-down like you're used to seeing.

Comment: yeah that's what i thought. But i don't see an option to bind a content type to a dropdown list. What am i missing.

Comment: @frosty I get what you mean now, I've updated the answer

Comment: great thanks, just what i was after. I'm using entity reference which is recommended by the reference module.